# Automatizar llamada a método en API NodeJS

Tags: nodejs, api, centos

Tengo desarrollada una **API REST** en **NodeJS** y necesito automatizar la llamada a un método que recupera la información de otra API(una de terceros) cada minuto para insertarla en mi **back-end**.

Mi SO es Centos 6.9 he leído por algunos post que es posible usar **cron** para automatizar tareas, pero no se si desde **NodeJS** es posible realizar esta tarea en el propio **back-end**.

¿Existe alguna forma de hacerlo desde **NodeJS**?

Gracias, Un saludo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mejor que usar `setInterval` es crear un cron.

**Ejemplo**

```
const  { CronJob } = require('cron');

// significa cada minuto
new CronJob('* * * * * *', function() {
  // llamar a método que consume el API
});
```

Para este ejemplo he usado el paquete [cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron). Puedes ver acerca de la sintaxis *cron* en [este enlace](http://www.nncron.ru/help/EN/working/cron-format.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Si tienes una función digamos helloWorld() y quieres automatizar su llamada, creo que podrías utilizar esta forma de hacerlo:

```
helloWorld();
setInterval(helloWorld, 30000);
```

Esto lo que haría es mientras tengas la app levantada en el servidor cada 30000 ms hará una llamada a la función que le pases por parametro.